# Trying to create test users through the Parse data browser fails

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to add a set of PFUsers in the Data browser with emails, validated, passwords and usernames so that I can test a feature in my iOS app. But as I add the users, the passwords are lost and the validated field will not stay as 'YES'.

How can I add users for testing?

Answer (score 0):

The process I've found success with is:

- Adding a row.
- Double clicking the appropriate cell to add a username then pressing enter.
- Doing the same for password.
- At the point it generates an ObjectId and I know the user has been stored.

In terms of a validated field, is that a column you added yourself or are you referring to the emailVerified column?

EDIT: In the case of emailVerified, you should be able to double click in the appropriate cell and it should present a drop-down of Boolean values that you can select.

Comment: ah, yes, i meant emailVerified.

Comment: Added to the answer to address emailVerified. Let me know if this works.

Comment: @user3240663 if this solved your question please click the checkmark to accept this answer, thanks